# std::tr1::function assignment and binding

Tags: c++, templates, tr1

I'm trying to learn how to best use the std::function and the std::bind facilities 
in the standard library - I'm interested in the TR1 versions, as that's what I 
have available for now and I'm not aware of the differences, if any, between the TR1 implementations and the C++11 ones.

So for the sake of the exercise I've set up to construct a simple let's say "dispatcher".
What I want is to be able to execute any function from the dispatcher based on some decisions taken later at runtime. I set up my class to have a general function data 
member like so:

```
class PoorDispatcher
{
 ...
 private:
     std::tr1::function<void()> m_f;
}
```

Then I assign to the data member the function I really want to call, similar to the below

```
...
m_f = std::tr1::bind(some_func, param1, param2, param3);
...
// then the call
m_f(); // SUCCESS
```

The above allows me to call successfully the function I want but I'm not sure it's the right thing to do. The questions:

1. Is the above usage scenario "sane"? Are there any better alternatives?
2. The above method poses a problem when trying to bind to a function which returns something. How can I retrieve the return value? (In my silliness I tired to cast the function objects without much success)

Answer (score 0):

The template argument to `std::function` is the actual function type. `void()` means a function which takes no arguments and returns no value.

If you want to store a function that returns a value you have to create a new function object. Or if you are not sure if the function will return something, use [boost.optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: I'm aware it's the actual function type. If I use bind the function call will work and it will call my function with the arguments, although the m_f is of type "void()". I cannot use boost, I have to stick to TR1. I want to avoid creating a new function object if that's possible.